# Option selected is equal to database value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to build a form to edit my content and have a select box. How do i make it so the rating score that was inputted into the database through the option value(1-5) will be the selected option when the user enters the edit form?

edit code:

```
                {{ Form::label('ratings_id', 'Ratings') }}
                <select class="form-control edit-form" name="ratings">
                    <option value="1">Very Poor</option>
                    <option value="2">Poor</option>
                    <option value="3">Fair</option>
                    <option value="4">Good</option>
                    <option value="5">Very Good/option>
                </select>
```

the old rating score(1-5) can be reached through this:

```
$reviews->rating
```

How do i make it so that the old rating score shows as the selected option value, when they user enters the form?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compare the value of the option with the `$rating` being edited.

```
<option value="2" {{ $rating->value === 2 ? 'selected' : '' }}>Poor</option>
```

Comment: Hi, i've had a similar issue and used this solution for my blade file. Works great in edit but i'm using the same form for add too and it's erroring with undefined variable in the ternary if. Should this be working fine in both add or edit or would i need to add a workaround? Thanks :)